# Can Tomura use all All for One quirks?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The My Hero Academia wikia lists Tomura as being capable of using 4 of the original All for One quirks.

- Super Regeneration
- Search
- Air cannon
- Radio waves

[Tomura Shigaraki wikia](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Tomura_Shigaraki)

What about the others, such as warping, strenght enhancer, impact recoil, multiplier, infrared ray, etc. Can he use all of them too?

Comment: A casual search suggests to me that the answer is contained in the very chapter you first see him use any of these abilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are reading the manga of my hero academia, so SPOILER WARNING.
shigaraki gains all for one in ( I think)) chapter 271, later, he uses radio waves on endeavor, which is one of all for one's powers, as chapters go on, we learn the doctor gave shigaraki all for one.

Answer (score -1):

No he can not. Unlike the One for All quirk it was stated that All for One is something that can't be passed on. All for One is something that the person keeps. This is also why the person that had/has All for One named is All for One.

this was shown in the second season, and as for the naming part is in the third or fourth season.